# Saving char in a file problems

Tags: c++, char, ofstream

Hey.
I have some problems writing char to a file with ofstream.
this is how the code looks (Just to show how it works. This is NOT the real code).

```
char buffer[5001];
char secondbuffer[5001];
char temp;
ifstream in(Filename here);
int i = 0;
while(in.get(secondbuffer) && !in.eof[])
{
i++;
}
for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
secondbuffer[j] = buffer[j];
}
ofstream fout(somefile);
fout << secondbuffer;

// end of program
```

The problem is that it reads the characters of the first file fine, but when it writes to the second file, it adds all characters from the first file, as its supposed to do, but when there are no more characters, it adds a lot of "Ì" characters in the end of file.

fx:

**file 1:**
abc

**file 2:**
abcÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ...

How can I prevent the program save "Ì" in the file?

EDIT2:

```
int i = 0;
    lenghtofFile++;
    while(fin.get(firstfileBuffer[i]) && !fin.eof())
    {
        i++;
        lenghtofFile++;
    }
    firstfileBuffer[i] = '\0';

    for(int j = 0; j < lenghtofFile; j++)
    {

        if(secondfileBuffer[j] != ' ' && secondfileBuffer[j] != '\0')
        {
        secondfileBuffer[j] = function(key, firstfileBuffer[j]);
        }

    }

    secondfileBuffer[lenghtofFile]='\0';

    fout << secondfileBuffer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to null-terminate secondbuffer. You are adding all the characters read from the stream, which do not include the trailing NULL.

on the line before `fout`, add

```
secondbuffer[j]='\0\';
```

Comment: Can you please check out my edit?
I still have the problem.

(I know the code is very bad, but I'm not good at programming. I hope you understand )

Comment: The problem now is that jj = lengthoffile-1.  You need it to be == lengthoffile.  (Actually, since you are now null terminating `firstfileBuffer`) you can just do `lengthoffile++;` before the copy loop.  This will ensure the null is copied.  Then you can get rid of the `jj` altogether.

Comment: Can you please check out my edited edit? (:D)
I does still not work.

Comment: @Janam: I feel you should try using in::getline, rather than in::get.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no terminating null character in your file.  When you read the file in, you get "abc" just fine, but the garbage that was sitting in secondbuffer when it was declared is still there, so writing "abc" to the beginning of it means that you have a 5001-length array of garbage that starts with "abc."

Try adding

`secondbuffer[i] = '\0';` after your for loop.

Comment: Can you please check out my edit?
I still have the problem.

(I know the code is very bad, but I'm not good at programming. I hope you understand )

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char buffer[5001];
  char secondbuffer[5001];
  ifstream in("foo.txt", ifstream::in);
  ofstream fout("blah_copy.txt");
  do
    {
      in.getline(buffer,5001);
      fout<<buffer;
    }
  while(!in.eof());
  in.close();
  fout.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: THanks for the answer. Right now I cant edit my code, but I'll rewrite it.